# Find the condition of $h$ satisfy $x^3+1$ divides $x^{2h+1}+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Find the condition of $h$ satisfy $x^3+1$ divides $x^{2h+1}+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and find the quotient polynomial.

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Can you do it over the integers? Can you work out whether the answer's any different mod 2?

Comment: To give another hint: Try enough many small values of $h$ so that you begin to see a pattern. For example when $h=2$ you are asked whether $x^5+1$ is divisible $x^3+1$. You can do polynomial division as follows first observe that
$$x^5+1=x^2(x^3+1)-x^2-1=x^2(x^3+1)-(x^2+1),$$
so $x^5+1$ is divisible by $x^3+1$ if and only if $x^2+1=x^{5-3}+1$ is. Try the same with $x^7+1$, $x^9+1$ to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your hint , I've solved it :D

Comment: Good! Why not write up your solution, and post it as an answer?

Comment: $h=3k$, $3k+1$ or $3k+2$. On case $h=3k$, $x^{2h+1}+1=x^{6k+1}+1=(x^3)^{2k}.x+1=x.((x^3)^{2k}-1)+x+1$, which don't divide $x^3+1$.....